# How to enable ssl for only one single page?

Tags: jakarta-ee, ssl, jboss7.x

I have a jsf application which deploy it to a ssl enabled jboss-7.1.1 . In my web.xml I have

```
    <security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTPS</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/secure/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>CONFIDENTIAL</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>

<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>HTTP</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <user-data-constraint>
        <transport-guarantee>NONE</transport-guarantee>
    </user-data-constraint>
</security-constraint>
```

I want to enable ssl only for pages inside secure folder but by this configuration ssl applied to entire web application.

How can I limit the ssl capability only to secure folder?

Comment: Only guess, you can you `@WebFilter` and all request for specific page redirect to `https`

Comment: it is more acceptable to use @WebFilter and redirect requests

Comment: Your security constraint for SSL seems to be correct, and it works in other servers correctly (forcing SSL only in the `/secured/*` path), so maybe a JBoss bug...